# Upper or Lower Case Optimisation on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Does anyone know if MS SQL Server text queries are optimised for upper or lower case strings?

I read somewhere the it was uppercase, but cant seem to find the reference to it again.  Of course if this is entierly wrong and no optimisation takes place, this would also be useful to know.

Thanks for your help.

CM

Comment: Apparently you can do it, and as other people have pointed out this is an install option do do with collation. My idea was to improve the performace of some queries, but apparently having a case sensative collation can cause problems, if you say miss a capital letter, the query will perform much worse than if you simply opted for a case insensative collation. But thanks again all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it depends on your install of SQL server. The default ones that I have seen are case insensitive.

Run `select serverproperty('SQLsortorderName')` if you get back `nocase_iso` it would mean that your searches are case insensitive. So using UPPER would give you the same results, but it would add a bit more work on the CPU.

Comment: And what if you get "bin_ascii_8"?

Comment: I've voted up this answer, but I want to make it clear that it's potentially more than just "a bit more work". Depending on the collation, you could end up doing index or even table scans instead of index seeks if you apply an UPPER() or LOWER() to an indexed field in a search condition.

Answer (score 5):

Since the default installations of SQL Server give you case insensitive searches, I am going out on a limb here and say that there is no upper or lower case optimization for searches.

Always adding UPPER() or LOWER() to convert text during a query will impact performance, depending on the volume of data being queried.  Do not use UPPER() or LOWER() if you don't have to.